# Regex match multiple items

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
<button {{ $attributes->class([
    'bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded',
    'bg-blue-600 px-3 py-2 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white rounded',
])->merge([
    'wire:click' => $click,
]) }}>
    {{ $label }}
</button>
```

I'm trying to get a VS Code extension (headwind) to match the stuff inside the `class` method single quotes via custom regex setting.

I have this regex which works a bit:

```
class\(([^)]*)\)
```

However the problem is its matching everything inside of the braces, which makes headwind mess up.

I need it to match each occurence of stuff inside the single quotes. How do I do this?

Comment: Try `(?:\G(?!\A)',\s*'|class\(\[\s*')\K[^']*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/es1U5W/1)).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're a genius

Comment: For some reason it's not working in VS Code though :/ Not sure if its a regex parsing issue. Here's what I'm using in my settings.json: "(?:\\G(?!\\A)',\\s*'|class\\(\\[\\s*')\\K[^']*"

Comment: I see thr `class\(\[` still contain single backslashes, you need to double *all* of them. Where in VSCode are you using the regex? In the document find and replace feature?

Comment: Well, looking at https://github.com/heybourn/headwind, it seems the flavor is ECMAScript. Try `(?<=\bclass\(\[\s*'(?:[^']*'\s*,\s*')*)[^']+(?=')`, i.e. ``(?<=\\bclass\\(\\[\\s*'(?:[^']*'\\s*,\\s*')*)[^']+(?=')`` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/es1U5W/2)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
(?<=\\bclass\\(\\[\\s*'(?:[^']*'\\s*,\\s*')*)[^']+(?=')
```

I.e., the `(?<=\bclass\(\[\s*'(?:[^']*'\s*,\s*')*)[^']+(?=')` escaped version.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/es1U5W/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=\bclass\(\[\s*'(?:[^']*'\s*,\s*')*)` - a position that is immediately preceded with a whole word `class([`, zero or more whitespaces, `'`, and then zero or more occurrences of any zero or more chars other than `'`, `'`, a `,` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces and then a `'` char
- `[^']+` - one or more chars other than `'`
- `(?=')` - a location that is immediately followed with a `'` char.